# KeyListener does not recognize when a key is pressed

Tags: java, keylistener, keyevent

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Tastatur implements KeyListener {
    
    private boolean[] keys = new boolean[66568];
    private boolean left, right, up, down, fw, bw;
    
    public void update() {  //Den boolean-Variablen werden keys zugewiesen
        this.left = this.keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT] || this.keys[KeyEvent.VK_A];
        this.right = this.keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT] || this.keys[KeyEvent.VK_D];
        this.fw = this.keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP] || this.keys[KeyEvent.VK_W];
        this.bw = this.keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN] || this.keys[KeyEvent.VK_S];
        this.up = this.keys[KeyEvent.VK_SPACE];
        this.down = this.keys[KeyEvent.VK_C] || this.keys[KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL];
    }
    
    public boolean getLeft() {
        return this.left;
    }
    
    public boolean getRight() {
        return this.right;
    }
    
    public boolean getFW() {
        return this.fw;
    }
    
    public boolean getBW() {
        return this.bw;
    }
    
    public boolean getUp() {
        return this.up;
    }
    
    public boolean getDown() {
        return this.down;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        keys[arg0.getKeyCode()] = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        keys[arg0.getKeyCode()] = false;
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    
}
```

So, my problem is that if i use e.g. getLeft() somewhere it always returns false, even if the key is pressed. The methods where i use it are completely fine (if i set getleft to true manually the other methods work) and i tracked down the error to this class. As it seems, it does not recognize any keyboard input at all. So the error must be somewhere in KeyPressed, KeyReleased or update(), right? As you can see, i'm not that experienced so i would really appreciate some help. Please help me to find the reason why my KeyListener does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your value is always false because you are setting false when the key is Released:
` @Override`
    `public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {` 
        `keys[arg0.getKeyCode()] = false;`
    `}`

You should remove that, and try another logic code.

Comment: are you sure? because i want it to be false when the key is released. it should only be true while the key is being hold. and in addition to that i figured out: it doesnt even go that far. if i put some sysout into keypressed and keyreleased it doesnt even go that far. so i assume it just does not recognize keys being pressed at all. but idk how to fix that either

Comment: @Shizuja well, do you register/add your key listener correctly? Can you show that code?

Comment: sure, i'll just paste the important method for the "left" action from another class here:

`if (this.tastatur.getLeft()) {`

    `this.kamera.aendern(0, -10, 0); `

    `for(iEntity entity : this.entities) {`

     `entity.aendern(0, 10, 0);`

    `}`

But as I said. As soon as I set the getLeft() method to true manually everything else works perfectly fine. So basically all i need is that if i press the "a" key, getLeft() returns true and as soon as i release it it is being set to false within the Tastatur (KeyListener) class

Comment: Please if you have code that is valuable for the question, be sure do [edit] your question and add the code there. Also, I asked if you register the key listener? For some text component to actually use your listener, it has to be registered (e.g. `yourTextField.addKeyListener(new Tastatur())`). See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html.

Comment: no its not being used for any sort of textfield. the keylisteners only purpose is to check if a key is being pressed or not. outside of the keylistener class i only work with the getLeft() method which checks if the left variable is true. and this is being checked over and over again since the keyboard.update() is in a update method itself. to answer your question: no its not registered anywhere but i dont think that it needs to be since i dont use the keylistener for anything else than changing the left variable between true and false within the keylistener class itself.

Comment: But who do you expect to call the `keyPressed()` / `keyReleased()` methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add the GUI and bind listener to some GUI component(`TextArea in`). Listener should contain logic (what to do if a key is pressed). Bellow is a minimal example.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TestKey extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JTextArea out;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TestKey();
    }
    public TestKey()
    {
        this.setSize(400, 200);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextArea in = new JTextArea(3,30);
        out = new JTextArea(3,30);
        add(in);
        add(out);
        in.addKeyListener(this);
        setVisible(true);   
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
    
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        out.setText(Character.toString(e.getKeyChar()));
        if(e.getKeyCode()==37)
        {
            out.setText("left");
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            out.setText("right");
        }
        System.out.println(e);
        
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   
    }

}
```

Output

[image: gui]